# Crystal Report Viewer not showing Images

Tags: image, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report v9x. In the data which is displayed in Crystal Report Viewer having the images. When i am trying to show the reports in the Crystal Report viewer, Images are not showing up.

Can any one give me some idea what to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried looking in your Web.config for the CrystalImageHandler (in httpHandlers section)?
I had to add a line to get my embedded images to show up:

```
<add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
```

Comment: The default behavior of ASP.NET Web Forms is that it adds a similar HTTP Handler to the web.config, but it has one extra tag preCondition="integratedMode", remove it and you are done

Comment: I also had the precondition which when removed the problem was not resolved, however I also confusingly had preCondition="runtimeVersionv2.0".  Removing this also fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you are all alright on the `Web.config` section, and if you are on `netFramework` greater than 4.0 try this.

On the `App_Start` Folder, look for `RouteConfig.cs` and comment out the following line

```
 Settings.AutoRedirectMode= RedirectMode,Permanent;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using ASP.NET MVC after 2 days of searching this solved my issue and image showed up the solution just add the following line to your file RouteConfig.cs

1- go to folder App_Start in your project

2- paste the following ignore line to the file RouteConfig.cs :

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*(CrystalImageHandler).*" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please also try to change .Net Framework mode from Integrated to Classic in the ApplicationPool configuration (IIS Application Pools)

Answer (score 0):

Try after reducing image resolution...For me It did the work.